# Qt drag resize widget?

Tags: qt

Suppose I have two Qt widgets in a vertical layout inside a parent widget.

Is there someway to add a control "border" between them such that when you click and drag the border area in between the two widegets you can change the relative area of the parent they take?

That is if you drag it up then the bottom widget gets resized bigger and the top widget gets resized smaller.

Comment: see also [Qt: Drag & Drop Widgets to Achieve Arbitrary Layout (Split) like in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149862/qt-drag-drop-widgets-to-achieve-arbitrary-layout-split-like-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All you need is [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html).

If you prefer creating widgets in code, look the docs from the link above.

If you like visual layout in QtDesigner/QtCreator, you may download my recent little [project](https://github.com/NIA/statistiq) and open in in QtCreator. In [`mainwindow.ui`](https://github.com/NIA/statistiq/blob/master/mainwindow.ui) you'll find a lot of QSplitters! You can create them using context menu: select two widgets -> right click -> Lay out -> Lay out vertically in a splitter.

In short, replace your vertical layout with a single QSplitter and add your two widgets to it as children.